# Scikit-learn installation error using pip on command line

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pip

I ran `pip install -U scikit-learn` in command line, scikit-learn and other dependencies begin installing, it returns "Successfully installed ". Then it shows

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\daniel\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 169, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
  File "c:\users\daniel\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 248, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "c:\users\daniel\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 507, in run
    self._handle_target_dir(
  File "c:\users\daniel\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 562, in _handle_target_dir
    shutil.rmtree(target_item_dir)
  File "c:\users\daniel\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\shutil.py", line 740, in rmtree
    return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)
  File "c:\users\daniel\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\shutil.py", line 613, in _rmtree_unsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  File "c:\users\daniel\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\shutil.py", line 618, in _rmtree_unsafe
    onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "c:\users\daniel\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\shutil.py", line 616, in _rmtree_unsafe
    os.unlink(fullname)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\Daniel\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\Lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\.libs\\libopenblas.FB5AE2TYXYH2IJRDKGDGQ3XBKLKTF43H.gfortran-win_amd64.dll'
```

Comment: Try with `pip install --user -U scikit-learn`

Answer (score 0):

I ran `pip install scikit-learn` rather than `pip install -U scikit-learn` and it worked fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).